# Removing an element by condition in an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am removing items from an `arrayList` called `itemList`.
I have made a `findItem` method to find an item by its `callNumber` and `copyNumber`.

In my `remove()` I use the `findItem()` to locate the item and then remove it. My problem is that I am still getting the `concurrentmodificationexception` error.

I have tried the enhanced for loop (which I know doesn't work), and I have tried the iterator (which should've worked) and still got the error.

This is my third strategy trying to get it to work.
What other strategies will traverse the list and remove an item and get around the `concurrentmodificationexception`?

```
/**
 * Finds an item by call number and copy number.
 *
 * @param callNumber the call number
 * @param copy the copy number
 * @return the item, if not found return null
 */
private Item getItem(String callNumber, int copy)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        Item item = itemList.get(i);
        if (item.getCallNumber() != null  
        && item.getCallNumber().equals(callNumber) 
        && item.getCopyNumber() == copy)
        {
            return item;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Deletes a item from the library.
 *
 * @param  callNumber  the call number of the item to be deleted.
 * @param  copy        the copy number of the item to be deleted.
 * @return      <code>true</code> if the item was deleted successfully,
 *              and <code> false</code> if the item was not deleted.
 */

 public boolean deleteItem(String callNumber, int copy)
{
    Item rItem = getItem(callNumber, copy);

    if(rItem == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (rItem.getCallNumber().equals(callNumber)
        && rItem.getCopyNumber() == copy)
    {
        itemList.remove(rItem);       
        numItems--;
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

My desired result is to remove the specified item from the list when the condition is true.

Comment: You need to use iterator to remove item from list.

Answer (score 0):

Remove item from list base on some condition.

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add(605);
        al.add(260);
        al.add(306);
        al.add(7);
        al.add(6);

        Iterator itr = al.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            int x = (Integer) itr.next();
            if (x < 300)
                itr.remove();
        }

        System.out.println(" ArrayList : " + al);
```

Comment: I’ve tried to use the iterator this exact same way(with a different condition)  and still got the error.